# How can I sort Week

Tags: sql

Here is the result I'm getting when I run a query to get Week. 
The problem is Week is not sorted in the right order. 
I do use ORDER BY and ASC/DESC, but I'm getting same result.

Please see the sample output:

```
Week
-------
Week-1
Week-10 
Week-11
Week-12
Week-2
Week-3
Week-4
Week-5
Week-6
Week-7
Week-8
Week-9
```

Is there any other way I can sort Week in right way?

Thanks in advance for the help?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: What query you perform

Comment: select week from (table-name) order by len(week), week this one sort my week column the way i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The columns is a string.  You can handle this by sorting by the length and then the value:

```
order by len(col), col
```

Note:  This assumes that the prefix is always the same, in this case "Week-".  Also, the `len()` function may have different names depending on the database.